# Selling ads on SO or SE sites based on Google search results alone?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, advertising, google

These Q&A sites are doing a bang up job at nailing page one of a relevant Google search without too much effort.

Question title goes in the web address, the title tag, meta tag, H1 tag, and with a few inbound links, bingo, it ends up on the first page of a Google search real easy.

I know about CTR and CPI but I'm wondering if one could sell banner space similar to how it's done on Stack Overflow based on Google search results alone?

For example, someone on [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) writes a question titled "cooking classes manhattan."

According to Google's keyword tool, that magic phrase gets 720 monthly searches under medium competition.

If that question ends up on the first page of Google search for that phrase, could someone sell a banner ad to a cooking school in New York for say a set fee per month?

How about allowing them to continue to do that for every keyword phrase/question title that ends up on page one of a Google search result?

Comment: I suggest trying to read your own question before posting, to make sure it's understandable and not a huge block of text.

Comment: SEO people are blessed.  Lots of opportunities for personal growth.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question. Surely a site like SO could do this, but to what end? It would lose its integrity and hard-earned credibility within weeks.

Also, even if you *wanted* to do this, I don't think the hassle to sell targeted ads that way would ever pay. They also already run ads.

Comment: It seems like SO IS already doing this.  I see those banner ads on each individual answer page. Don't you??

Comment: @Nick you are talking about selling targeted ads depending on incoming search engine keywords, which is something SO doesn't do.

Comment: I'm really trying to figure out a way for all these Stack Exchange sites to perhaps earn a little money.  They could go the Adsense route but I distinctly remember that SO did that for a few weeks only to abandon it because the money it brought in was so low.  I was thinking that trying to sell targeted ads directly to businesses could be better way?